# Dimension of null space of symmetric binary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be binary $n \times n$ matrices.

**Edit:** That is to say, $A,B \in M_n(GF(2))$ acting on the natural vector space $GF(2)^n$.

Suppose also that $B$ is symmetric.

What can be said about the dimension of the null space of $B+ABA^T$ (over $GF(2)$)?

For example is it nicely bounded above?

Thanks.

**Edit:** More specifically, what can be said if $B \neq 0$ and $A$ preserves no subspace of $GF(2)^n$

Comment: The field is important. When the field is real, we always have $\operatorname{nullity}(B+ABA^T)\le\operatorname{nullity}(B)$. But this isn't true when the field is $GF(2)$. E.g. when $B=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}$ and $A=I_2$, we have $\operatorname{nullity}(B+ABA^T)=2>1=\operatorname{nullity}(B)$.

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat - I have added an extra assumption of interest

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I will remove my comment, the $GF(2)^n$ appeared after my comment.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand, @copper.hat. To me the term *binary* means $GF(2)$ (possibly including extension fields), but I have seen posters to whom it simply means $\{0,1\}$ *without specifiying the ambient ring*, and that makes a difference. Sorry about that. Deleting.

Comment: Hopefully this is fully clarified now. Thanks